# Oracle find match polygon with longitude and latitude

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I want to check a longitude and latitude is inside a polygon area in Oracle Spatial.
I have try these code

```
SELECT * FROM
MZONE a WHERE a.category = 'zone'
AND SDO_INSIDE(SDO_GEOMETRY(2007,8307,SDO_POINT_TYPE(51,32,NULL),NULL,NULL),
a.AREA.SDO_ORDINATES) = 'TRUE';
```

and result error with

> SQL Error [29900] [99999]: ORA-29900: operator binding does not exist
> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_INSIDE'

Comment: Try with the first param of SDO_INSIDE is the column in the table, and the second sdo_geometry

Comment: I have been tried and work. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM MZONE a 
WHERE a.category = 'zone'
AND SDO_CONTAINS(
  a.area, 
  SDO_GEOMETRY(2007,8307,SDO_POINT_TYPE(51,32,NULL),NULL,NULL)
) = 'TRUE';
```

The first operand to the spatial predicate is the column you search (= your areas). The second one is your search "window" (here a point).

**Important:** The operator should be `SDO_CONTAINS()`: you are searching for the area(s) that **contain** your search point. Use `SDO_INSIDE()` to do the reverse (= search for points that are **inside** an area).